# Chrome - Disable Longpress Copy / Paste Bubble for Input Boxes

Tags: css, google-chrome, touch, textselection

In Chrome, when I longpress (with my finger on my touchscreen) on text on any webpage, it selects words and shows a little popup for copying that text (and pasting if it's an input field).

I've determined that `user-select: none` will disable this feature for body text, but setting `user-select: none` has no effect on input fields, `<textarea></textarea>`, `<input/>`, etc., and longpressing on text in input fields will still show this bubble.

[image: Longpress Text Popup]

I need to disable this popup, ideally with CSS / JS / HTML, or, in worst case, with a Chrome flag. What are my options for disabling this?

Chrome 77
Windows 10

TIA!